# Alternative to base.OnAppearing in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Basic questions, is there an alternative to base.OnAppearing which will only run once?

Currently, in OnAppearing I have a script which generates frames based on a result of a query. If I lock the screen & then unlock, it queries again & add the result to the bototm of the list, essentially duplciating results.

I could add a check on a HasLoaded boolean first, but surely there must be a built in way of only executing script Onload? I looked through the properties of base & can't see anything obvious.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to move your script to the constructor or create an `Init` method which is called from outside (if possible). When you create your page, before you call `PushAsync` just call `Init` on your `Page`'s instance.

OnAppearing / OnDisappearing is a not so good place for such code, as documented in the Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical).

> Calls to the OnDisappearing and OnAppearing overrides cannot be treated as guaranteed indications of page navigation. For example, on iOS, the OnDisappearing override is called on the active page when the application terminates.

So its possible, that your script is skipped.

Comment: It was that easy! Wasn't doing anything in OnAppearing that couldn't be done in the constructor. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Page constructor will run just once.

If you need to do a lot of work then you can use `Task.Run` from there.

Comment: Thanks for this - have made amendments quite easily. Also noted your advice on Task.Run...